# Measure time in SICStus Prolog

Tags: performance, time, prolog

I want to measure how long a program takes to be executed to be able to compare the efficiency when I change parts of the program. For that I use

```
statistics(runtime,[Start,_]),
my_program,
statistics(runtime,[Stop,_]),
T is Stop - Start.
```

How "exact" is that? The problem is that I get different results for multiple executions, although it should do the exact same thing each time.
The program creates/opens/edits files on my computer. Might that be a problem?
Thx.

Comment: Measuring performance on modern computers is extremely tricky. Also note that `runtime` does not include GC-time. I/O further blurs things. And you have to run things quite often.

Comment: There was a typo in the second statistics call.

Comment: In more  recent versions, there is also `total_runtime` which includes GC and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably use a dedicated machine, not running other things.

To measure how long a program runs in SICStus Prolog, use walltime:

```
statistics(walltime,[Start,_]),
my_program,
statistics(walltime,[Stop,_]),
T is Stop - Start.
```

It will also measure GC and I/O. The statistics/2 options of SICStus Prolog are documented here:

https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.0.3/html/sicstus/ref_002dmgc_002dove_002dsta.html#ref_002dmgc_002dove_002dsta